# When i get SelectedItem in combobox return System.Data.DataRowView

Tags: c#, combobox

this is a function for retrive two field in sql to combobox :
**Code :**

```
public void FillCmbKala()
    {
        cmbKala.Items.Clear();
        objCon.Connecting();
        string SQL = "SELECT [kID],[kName] FROM tblKala ORDER BY kName";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(objCon.StrCon))
        {
              using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, cn))
              {

                  cn.Open();

              try
              {
                  adapter.Fill(ds);
              }
              catch (SqlException e)
              {

                  MessageBox.Show("There was an error accessing your data of 'Kala'. DETAIL: " + e.ToString());
              }
              finally
              {
                 cn.Close();
              }
          }
     }
     cmbKala.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
     cmbKala.DisplayMember = "kName";
     cmbKala.ValueMember = "kID";
}
```

when i use the combobox return System.Data.DataRowView !

For Example :

```
string str= cmbKala.SelectedItem;
```

**result is :**  str= System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: What is the result of `cmbKala.SelectedItem.ToString()` in your case?

Comment: Result not change,return str=System.Data.DataRowView ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

As `SelectedItem` returns Object. It returns specific row object which is selected. Here is how you will get value:

```
DataRowView oDataRowView = cmbKala.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
string sValue = string.Empty;

if (oDataRowView != null) {
   sValue = oDataRowView.Row["kName"] as string;
}
```

Comment: Result not change,return str=System.Data.DataRowView ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. How about getting value from `DataRowView`?

Comment: but when i want return SelectedValue is return Null ? how i return kID ?

Answer (score 5):

```
 DataRowView dv = (DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedItem;
        string s = (string)dv.Row["kName"];
        int m1 = (int)dv.Row["kID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are selecting IS a DataRowView. You should select the id of the item or the text instead right? Like string str= cmbKala.SelectedItem.Text or string str= cmbKala.SelectedItem.Value?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is old, but I just wanted to let you guys know that If you get this error make sure you are using

```
    ComboBoxName.DisplayMemberPath = "name of the column that you want to show in the combobox (ex: name)"  
    ComboBoxName.SelectedValuePath = "name of the column (ex:id)";
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS WILL DEFINITELY HELP TO YOU**

on the load Event you want to Just Write this code

```
onformload()
{

     cmb_dept.Items.Clear();

     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"DATA SOURCE=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;INTEGRATED SECURITY=true;INITIAL CATALOG=EMPLOYEE;");

     conn.Open();

     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select dept_id, dept_name from department", conn);

     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

     DataSet ds = new DataSet();

     adapter.Fill(ds);

     cmb_dept.ValueMember = "dept_id";

     cmb_dept.DisplayMember = "dept_name";

     cmb_dept.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

 }
```

## try using Use the code where you want to access the values........

```
string dept = cmb_dept.Text; MessageBox.Show("val=" + dept);
YOUR combobox.text = System.Data.DataRowView Will be Solved ##
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on C# WPF:

```
Textbox.Text = (listbox.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row["Purpose"] as string;
```