# Populating ComboBox with values from SQL Column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, combobox

I am trying to populate a combobox that is disabled until a value in a previous combobox is selected, with all data within a specific column within a SQL Server table.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
private void cboManufacturor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string manufacturor = this.cboManufacturor.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (!cboModel.Enabled)
    {
        cboModel.Enabled = true;
    }

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Program.conString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        string queryString = "SELECT * FROM tblStock WHERE Manufacturor=@Manufacturor";

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturor", manufacturor);

        SqlDataReader DR;

        using (DR = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (DR.Read())
            {
                cboModel.Items.Add((string)DR["Model"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Dean

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to say what the problem i was encountering actually was! When a value in the original ComboBox (cboManufacturor) is selected, the second ComboBox (cboModel) is enabled, but no values are added.

Comment: what's the problem in your code ?

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the post with the problem i am facing

Comment: Check if you get data from query ?

Comment: How would you recommend doing this? Thanks!

Comment: You can use a Breakpoint or `MessageBox` in `while` loop to check if SqlDataReader has data.

Comment: Ok so I used a breakpoint and found that the value being assigned to the manufacturor variable is : "System.Data.DataRowView".
I then added a breakpoint to another part of my code that uses the same method and that returns the correct value.

Comment: try to use code in answer.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865113/when-i-get-selecteditem-in-combobox-return-system-data-datarowview .Provided  `toString()` returns `System.Data.DataRowView` , most probably you  set your cbo similar way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `manufacturor` variable is : "`System.Data.DataRowView`" because you use `SelectedItem`, `SelectedItem` is the data object that is bound to the ComboBox's data source, you can use :

```
string manufacturor = this.cboManufacturor.Text;
```

or cast SelectedItem to DataRowView, then retrieve the appropriate value from it like this :

```
DataRowView oDataRowView = this.cboManufacturor.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
string manufacturor = string.Empty;

if (oDataRowView != null) {
   manufacturor = oDataRowView.Row["YourFieldName"] as string;
}
```

Comment: I Tried this previously, I however tried again with a breakpoint and the result is the same as above. Thanks!

Comment: That has worked! Thankyou! if you can, update the answer to the above comment and i will accept as the answer, also if possible, could you add some information as to what the issue was if you know? just so i know for future! Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! Thank you too :)