# Not able to access the valuemember of a combobox and list box with simple statement

Tags: c#, combobox, listbox

I am trying to populate a list box based off of the selected value of a `combobox`. I can get the displayed text of the selected option of the combo box but but I can't get the value of the selected `combobox` entry. Here is the code for the `combobox`:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\ProviderPayAppFolder2\PPTF\PPTF\PPTF.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
conn.Open();
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
string strQuery = "SELECT EMPFNAME + ' ' + EMPLNAME AS NAME FROM EMPLOYEES";
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
sqlCmd.CommandText = strQuery;
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
adpt.Fill(ds2);
cmbEmployees.DisplayMember = "NAME";
cmbEmployees.ValueMember = "Id";
cmbEmployees.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
```

and here is the code for the listbox:

```
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Brendon\Desktop\ProviderPayAppFolder2\PPTF\PPTF\PPTF.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
conn2.Open();
DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();
string strQuery2 = "UPDATE TASKS SET WORKING = '" + cmbEmployees.ValueMember + "' WHERE Id = '" + listBox2.ValueMember + "'";
SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand(strQuery2, conn2);
sqlCmd2.CommandText = strQuery2;
sqlCmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I've experimented with different syntaxes but the only two things I can get is "Id" or `System.Data.DataRowView`
I know it's probably something simple but how do I access the value of both a combo box and a list box ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865113/when-i-get-selecteditem-in-combobox-return-system-data-datarowview

Comment: Your query didn't have a field `Id`  : `"SELECT EMPFNAME + ' ' + EMPLNAME AS NAME FROM EMPLOYEES"` ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your comment before, I'll try including an ID field in the query. Thanks.

Comment: Yes! Because you assign `Id` to `ValueMember` of comboBox, `cmbEmployees.ValueMember = "Id";` and the field `Id` not exist in DataSource of combobox `DataSet ds2`.