# Viewing list box selected item data to textbox

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm new to `c#` and I've using `xampp` for `mysql` connection with visual studio.
I'm trying to View list box selected item data that is connected to sql database table to text field when the item is clicked.
I'm using this code but nothing happens when i click the item..

```cs
private void listbox_user_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=table1;Uid='root';Pwd='';SslMode=none");
    sqlcon.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Name='"+listbox_user.SelectedItem.ToString()+"'";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
         txtbox_name.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
         txtbox_username.Text = dr["Username"].ToString();
         txtbox_pwd.Text = dr["Password"].ToString();
    }
    sqlcon.Close();
}
```

The database is connected and the data is there but nothing happens

[image: here is form design]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# and MySQL .NET Connector - Any way of preventing SQL Injection attacks in a generic class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775692/c-sharp-and-mysql-net-connector-any-way-of-preventing-sql-injection-attacks-i)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection may be worth reading.

Comment: Run to the breakpoint on the `foreach` line. Type `?listbox_user.SelectedItem.ToString()` into the `Immediate Window`. What appears? What about for `?dt.Rows.Count`?

Comment: The result i got is this ?dt.Rows.Count
0
?listbox_user.SelectedItem.ToString()
"System.Data.DataRowView"

Comment: You really should be using `using` statements. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17592858/1684720 as an example of how to do so.

Comment: I'd suggest having a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865113/when-i-get-selecteditem-in-combobox-return-system-data-datarowview .